# Checking if a String Contains Another, if so at what Indexes

Tags: java, string, hashmap

I have not been able to find a solution to this online, StackOverflow or elsewhere, so I thought I'ld post here.

Suppose there's a string called String1. There are also many other strings, such as StringA, String B, StringC... StringZ.

String1 will contain only one of those strings (StringA-Z), and it may contain extra characters in front and behind it (in a sense, StringA-Z is hidden within String1)

Now, how would one check which StringA-Z is contained within String1, and at what indexes, so it would be possible to trim String1 (or leave it as is if that's the case) in a way that it ends up matching the string it contained?

Thanks 
- cp15

EDIT: Solved. Thanks to everyone who replied. Looks like there were other questions like this on StackOverflow, I remember reading one or two, but I thought my case was different. Turns out I was just confusing indexOf() with substring().

Comment: is this your assignment? or else post your code, will help then.

Comment: @NomeshDeSilva Nope, not an assignment. Just coding recreationally, and got stumped. I guess I could try re-wording it and adding more information

Comment: @andrewdleach Not looking to become or am a developer, just coding for fun at the moment. Posted this question because I couldn't find anything else like it online, thought it might come in help if someone else runs into a similar problem in the future.

Comment: @ChillzDude do you need to use a map here, or do you really just want to find whether or a given string contains one of several possible strings?

Comment: @JonathanThoms I guess I don't absolutely have to use the map, but as of now its the only way I could think of... wait, nvm. Just thought of another way. Thanks for triggering that thought.

Comment: @ChillzDude have you considered using regular expressions? btw, kudos on starting to code on your own; this is how it starts.

Comment: @JonathanThoms Yeah, I actually did use some regex in my code for replacing certain parts of the string. But anyways, problem solved now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using indexof method?

```
If (string1.indexof(stringA) != -1){
    // it does exists. Do something with it..
```

}

Just of the top of my head, but if i understand you correctly then this should be enough

Comment: Right on :) I knew I could use indexOf and check if it was not -1, but I didn't know I could use my it as indexOf(stringA). Thought it had to be indexOf(someInt), and as I'm typing this I've realized I've been mixing up indexOf with substring(beginIndex, endIndex), which both require int's hence the confusion, for some reason. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would use a `HashMap` in which every key maps to itself, so I'm going to just use a list of `String`s (`stringList`) to show how to do this.

```
for (String stringX : stringList) {
    // Get the starting index of stringX in string1
    int index = string1.indexOf(stringX);
    // index will be -1 if stringX is not within string1
    if (index != -1) {
        // Do what you want here, then break since there is only one match
        // and we already found it.
        break;
    }
}
```

If you really wanted to use a `HashMap` (I'll call it `stringMap`), simply change `stringList` to `stringMap.keySet()` or `stringMap.values()` (since they are both the same).

Comment: Yes, I just realized that and was editing the post as you replied. I think I've found a solution, thanks for your help

Comment: @ChillzDude glad you were able to figure it out, please accept an answer (the green checkmark) if one of them helped answer your question.